# Binding datepicker with an Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

So, I have created a JSFiddle that actually works for this:

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemahony/jdz0vvkv/1/)

```
var datePicker = angular.module('JBenchApp', []);

datePicker.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

But when I move this into my application it doesn't work with the exact same code.

Some background:

1. I have an ng-app="JBenchApp" in my HTML tag.
2. I have declared my links to JQuery, JQuery-UI, and Angular in the head of my index.html file
3. I have a calendar.html file that is a partial that gets displayed using the angular routing and the ng-view directive. This has the tag:

All gets displayed properly and onLoad I can see that the directive is bound. I then click on the datepicker and nothing happens. No errors appear in the console either.

Everything in the JSFiddle above works. I have copied it exactly as is into my code and it just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT TO INCLUDE WHAT'S IN THE HEAD:

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: make sure you're including `jquery-ui.css ` & `jquery-ui.min.js ` in your index file.

Comment: I have the following in my index.html:

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: There is no error. As stated in the question, the console shows nothing.

Comment: try to include external libraries without using protocol. like `//cdn.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/` instead `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/`

Comment: Thanks! Excluding the protocol accomplished nothing. Problem still exists and no errors in the console.

Comment: charlietfl, when I paste the links into the browser I see the CSS, so I am certain they are valid paths. I edited my question to include what I am declaring in the head and you will see that the paths are correct.

Comment: Why do I feel this has something to do with scope since ng-view is being used?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after staring at this code and staring at this code, it struck me. The directive is named jqdatepicker and the call to the directive is jdatepicker (no "q"). Doh!